# Google VR Unity - Stereotypical-view and gyroscope are not working on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gyroscope

I'm new here, I hope my post met the guidelines and can provide detail as much as possible.

**What I was trying to do:**

- Compile GVRDemo scene straight from `GoogleVRForUnity_1.70.0` package to APK on
  Unity 3D and install it on Android device.

**What the problem was:**

- App is running, but the stereotypical-View and gyroscope didn't work
- Other VR related apps works fine on the android device.

**What I've tried to do:**

- Switched to Android platform
- Check the Player Setting on Unity for Virtual Reality supported as Cardboard.

**Specification used:**

- Unity `Version 2017.1.0f3`
- Smartphone `ASUS Z00AD`, `Android v5.0`, Gyroscope available
- `GVR Unity v1.70.0` package

What should I do to make the stereotypical-view and the gyroscope to working?

Thank you, sorry for any lack of information.

Comment: That particular phone appears to be running an Intel CPU, have you tried it on a different (ARM) based device?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting, I haven't tried it to ARM based device. But in Unity, I set the android device filter on the player settings to FAT(ARMv7+x86) with minimum API level at 19. Also the Build System is set to Internal(Default), but I doubt it's because of the Unity's Build System.

Answer (score 0):

download gvr sdk source instead of unitypackage